# Tkinter - Can you store a whole object in a treeview element's values?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I add elements to my treeview widget in this way:

```
treeview.insert("","end",model_name,text=model_name, values=(model))
```

Where `model` is a `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline`:

```
>> type(model)
<class 'sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline'>
```

I retrieve this element in this way:

```
model = treeview.item(item_selected)["values"][0]
```

But when I do it, the type of model is different:

```
>> type(model)
<class 'str'>
```

Now, I would like to know if it is possible for the object to not change type when being stored in the treeview. Note: in my treeview I do not show the model (this treeview has only one column). The only reason for storing the model inside the treeview element is to avoid the creation of a separate, new dictionary elsewhere

Comment: No,I think you couldn't.Maybe you need to use a dictionary,In tkinter,`values` doesn't like a dict,[Read in document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#item-options).

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I've already read the docs, and they don't mention what value type is accepted, do they?

Comment: You could try it,I pass `set`,`list`,`tuple`,`str`,`int`.Only `str` and `int` could get.